# How to expand div and push the heading down/up using CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Following is the excerpt from my html page.

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="sec_inform" >
      <h1 class='inf_head'>Some heading goes here</h1>
      <div class='inf_desc'>And here goes the description. Two Liner description actually. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sec_pic" >
      <img class='prd_logo' src="https://src.com/abc.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

After styling it looks fine. ( See here: http://jsbin.com/orucel/1 )

Now, what I want is if `.inf_desc` contains huge text then :

1. `.inf_head` should move to top ( If you see the code, I have used padding-top for `sec_inform`, so it should somehow change the padding-top to 0 . [May be there is some other property which does the same thing ]  )
2. Another desired thing, but not important, if `.inf_desc` contains really too much text then `.inf_desc` should grow and eventually `#sec_inform` and `#main_container` too should grow.

How can I do this?

If at all jQuery is required then I am okay with that, but I will prefer some CSS only solution.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method will help you.

Comment: You mean there is no CSS only solution? Would you please explain how $.animate() will help in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use tables to push content according to the height, but tables are not recommended but in this situation instead of putting jquery we can achieve this in pure CSS and some HTML Tags, IF anybody can achieve this pure DIV's it will be intresting to see.

http://jsbin.com/orucel/4/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body id='jsbinBody'>

  <div id="main_container">
    <div id="sec_inform" >
      <table valign="middle" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" height="100%">
            <div>
              <h1 class='inf_head'>Some heading goes here</h1>
              <div class='inf_desc'>And here goes the description. Two Liner description actually.
                Use this text indeed. 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sodales, nibh sit amet bibendum consectetur, elit sem laoreet erat, interdum tempor arcu augue nec ligula. Mauris eget leo mi, a consectetur metus. Cras sagittis ultricies ipsum feugiat tincidunt. Aenean augue dolor, porta at facilisis non, sollicitudin vitae justo. Quisque nec tristique mauris. Praesent a ultricies lacus. Duis pretium mi neque. Aenean quis orci sed dolor pulvinar lacinia in id risus. Sed arcu neque, ultrices non viverra et, tincidunt ut lacus. Vestibulum porttitor elementum consequat. Curabitur ac ante orci.
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>        
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div id="sec_pic" >
      <img class='prd_logo' src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVYSnOi8NlsD7QNJoz2Do1Lcm8qoiCH3I-EWkEuVgg_sypqpjQ8Q" />
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
   border: 1px dashed red;  
}

#main_container{
  height: 500px;
  width:800px;
}

#sec_inform{
  border-color: green;
  height: 86%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 0px;
}


#sec_pic{
  border-color: blue;

  float: right;
  height: 86%;
  width: 38%;
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 0px;
}

.prd_logo{
   display: block;
   margin: 50% auto;
}


.inf_desc{
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #666;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #333;
  margin:0px;
}

#jsbinBody{
  font-family: Lucida grande;
}
```